# Ввод данных в map

Tags: c++, map, stl

У меня есть код который выводит заранее заданные возраст, рост и вес. Как переобразовать это что бы можно было вводить выше указанные данные?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class People {
public:
    int age, height, weight;
    People(int age, int height, int weight) {
        this->age = age;
        this->height = height;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
};

pair<string, int> *f() {
    return new pair<string, int>("Vlad, ", 16);
}

int main() {
    map<string, People> obj = map<string, People>();
    obj.insert(pair<string, People>("Name", People(16, 180, 80))); // age, height, weight

    for (pair<string, People> p : obj) {
        cout << "Name: " << p.first << " Age: " << p.second.age << " Height: " << p.second.height << " Weight: " << p.second.weight << "\n\n";
    }

    cout << f()->first << " " << f()->second << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, зачем нужна `f()`, но из нее утекает память.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
//...
#include <iterator>
using Pair = std::pair<std::string, People>;
using In = std::istream_iterator<Pair>;
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, const Pair& p)
{
    auto [a, b] = p;
    input >> a >> b.age >> b.height >> b.weight;
    return input;
}    
int main() {        
    map<string, People> obj;
    //...
    obj.insert(In(std::cin), In()); 
    //...   
    return 0;
}
```

Можно и по разному...